# How to dynamically create elements with *ngFor from an array of tag names?

Tags: angular

I am creating a website builder and need to dynamically render html element where the tags and content are supplied from an array. Is that possible with `*ngFor`?

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngFor="let element of elements">
      <{{element.tag}}>
        {{ element.text }}
      </{{element.tag}}>
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  elements = [
    { tag: 'div', text: 'foo' },
    { tag: 'p', text: 'bar' },
  ]
}
```

To keep things simple, this example is flat but my actual use case is recursive with `children`

```js
export interface ElementDescriptor {
  tag: string
  text?: string
  children?: ElementDescriptor[]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by @MarkoEskola in his answer, you can use [Angular Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2). From your model, you create the text content with `createText()`, then create the element with `createElement()` and then add to its parent with `appendChild()`. Repeat the process for descendants.

This is untested (coded here on SO):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <div #root></div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  elements: ElementDescriptor = [
    { tag: 'div', text: 'foo' },
    { tag: 'p', text: 'bar' },
  ]

  @ViewChild('root', { static: false }) private root: ElementRef;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addChildren(this.root, this.elements);
  }

  private addChildren(parent: HTMLElement, children: ElementDescriptor[]): void {
    for (var child of children) {
      this.addChild(parent, child.tag, child.text);
      if (child.children) {
        this.addChildren(child, children);
      }
    }
  } 

  private addChild(parent: HTMLElement, childTag: string, childText: string): void {
    const el = this.renderer.createElement(childTag);
    const text = this.renderer.createText(childText);

    this.renderer.appendChild(el, text);
    this.renderer.appendChild(parent, el);
  }
}
```

You might also need to do some checks to ensure adding a text to an element is valid, or adding a specific element as child to another does not invalidate your component's HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add the elements to the DOM in the code by using Angular **Renderer2** and its methods. I don't think this is possible only using ngFor and template.
https://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-4-renderer2-example